# How can I integrate my test cases written in WebdriverIO-Cucumber-Typescript framework with HP ALM?

Tags: webdriver-io, hp-alm

We are using WebdriverIO-Cucumber-Typescript to write our test cases and executing it in local machine & also through Jenkins CICD. We want to integrate our automation test cases with HP ALM tool for test management and execution.
Is there any way to integrate webdriverIO-Cucumber test automation test cases with HP ALM?